# Loop through req.body element, jumps into string when its only 1 Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, post

I have a problem with lopping through my `req.body.email`.
As long as there are minimum 2 `emails` my obj is printed out like this:

```
{
  users: [
    { email: 'sadda@gmail.com', role: 'read' },
    { email: 'dsads@web.de', role: 'Admin' }
  ]
}
```

So everything is correct here. But as soon as I only have 1 `email` it loops through the individual letters making the obj look like this:

```
{
  users: [
    { email: 't', role: 'read' },
    { email: 'e', role: 'read' },
    { email: 's', role: 'read' },
    { email: 't', role: 'read' }
  ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
router.post('/test/:proID', async (req, res) => {
    const projectID = parseInt(req.params['proID'], 10) || 0;
    var obj = {};
    obj.users = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < req.body.email.length; i++) {
      obj.users[i] = { email: req.body.email[i], role: req.body.right[i]
      };
    console.log(req.body.email.length);
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(obj);
```

How can I fix this? Also when I have only 1 Email, my `req.body.email.length` shows the number of letters, instead of the length of the object.
So I assume when there's only 1 Email it's just a String and if multiple my `req.body.email` is an object?

How can I handle this efficiently?

Comment: What does your request body look like?

Comment: _"But as soon as I only have 1 email"_ - Then fix your backend that it always returns an array. It makes no sense to return different types depending on the amount of elements.

Comment: If you can't fix the backend just `concat` it before looping `const body = [].concat(req.body);` if it's an array already nothing will change, otherwise it will make it an array.

Comment: @Andreas I get my emails/rights from a form which is dynamically generated. So I have multiple inputs with name="email" and name="right". I have no influence on how its returned

Comment: The mails are the result of a request for `/test/:proID`, so there is some "backend" that generates that list. And this "backend" has to always return an array of mails, regardless of the amount of emails (0, 1, 10, 1000, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the type of the `email` field in your response body depends on the number of addresses. In case there is only one address, it is a `string`, if there is more than one address, it's an `Array`. If you can't change the API to always return an `Array`, you could check the data type on the client:

```
if (Array.isArray(req.body.email)) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```